# Can't get the desired return value in Python

Tags: python, return-value, montecarlo, pi

I made a program to approximate the value of pi using the Monte Carlo method in python:

```
import random
import math

N_tot = 0
N_hits = 0
centerX = 0.5
centerY = 0.5

# precision = input('input number of decimals for approximation: ')


def inside_circle(randomX,randomY):
    if(math.sqrt((centerX-randomX)**2+(centerY-randomY)**2)<=0.5):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def estimate_pi():
    N_tot = 0
    N_hits = 0

    for i in range(0,100000):
        if(inside_circle(random.random(),random.random())==True):
            N_hits = N_hits+1
            N_tot = N_tot+1
        else:
            N_tot = N_tot+1

    result = N_hits/N_tot
    return result

print(estimate_pi())
```

When I run this, the console prints 0.0 and I have no idea why? Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: [works on my machine](https://ideone.com/c7LOoL). (well, OK, it prints approximately pi/4 rather than just approximately pi, but that's still better than 0.0)

Comment: In Python 2, if you calculate `n/m` for two ints where `0<n<m`, then you get zero, because `/` does int division on ints.

Comment: @khelwood, but if OP is to be believed, he's seeing 0.0, not 0. The former is a float, so I don't think truncated integer division is the problem.

Comment: @Kevin with emphasis on **if**

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in Python 2, `N_hits/N_tot` is treated as integer division. Use `float(N_hits)/N_tot` and it should work.

By the way, the thing you're approximating here is not pi but pi/4, as you're in the upper right quarter of the circle. Multiply that by 4 to get the correct result.